# How to get the count after every month in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Below is my query output

```
Milsestone   Date        raised  answered
  M1       1/2/2012      2       1
  M1       2/2/2012      4       2
  M2       2/3/2012      5       1
  M2      12/3/2012      4       2
  M3       5/3/2012      10      5
```

I need to design report like below

```
  Milestone  Date    Raised  Answred
   M1        1/2/2012   2     1
   M1        2/2/2012   4     2
              Feb       6     3
   M2         2/3/2012  5     1
   M2        12/3/2012  4     2
              Mar       9     3
   M3         5/3/2012  10    5
              Mar       10    5
```

How to design report in ssrs 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create table in your report
2. Set proper Dataset to it
3. Add new Group (by Month of your Date column)
4. Add total row below in group
5. Fill your total row as you want.

If you want, I can add some pics here.

**EDIT**:

[image]
[fullview here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDmbG.png)

The result is:
[image]

Comment: Okay. Wait for a few minutes. I will create some example.