# Microsoft Report: Use a table in column of another table

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting, rdlc, tabular

I need a table that represent list of all `Projects` table data in report. But I need a column to show list of people that works on current project(row).

When put a table in another table column in Microsoft Report (RDLC), I can't change `DataSetName` of this table to `People`.

I need a table like this:

```
RowNumber  |  Project Name  | Total People | People List
______________________________________________________________
    1      |    Project 1   |      2       | Name | Surname
           |                |              |_______________
           |                |              |  AA  |   AA
           |                |              |  BB  |   BB

--------------------------------------------------------------
    2      |    Project 2   |      4       | Name | Surname
           |                |              |_______________
           |                |              |  AA  |   AA
           |                |              |  EE  |   EE
           |                |              |  FF  |   FF
           |                |              |  DD  |   DD
```

How can I do this? Any one has sample or trick for this ?

Comment: You don't need to use a different DataSetName for the inside tables. The whole outside table will use a DataSetName and you should try using some kind of grouping by project id as Chepene mentioned in his answer. That should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't very difficult. 
Just look from the direction of people.

1. Create table.
2. Create Class for this report.. smth like:

   public class PersonInfo
   {
       public string LastName { get; set; }

   ```
   public string FirstName { get; set; }

   public string ProjectName { get; set; }
   ```

   }
3. Dataset for your table (for example) is a collection of personInfos..
4. Group by ProjectName
5. RowNumber... try smth like this:

   > =RunningValue(Fields!ProjectName.Value, CountDistinct, Nothing)

Everything is ready!

p.s. : if there will be problems with 'Total' column (though I don't think), you may add one more property to class and set value you need.

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858857/how-to-get-the-count-after-every-month-in-ssrs-2008/11860080#11860080) answer will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Chepene. I need to add List<People> to Project class or add Name, Surname and ... to Project class?

Comment: As I know, rdlc has problem with collections in class... (If you will know how create it with collection, let me know ;))

It maybe bad idea to add information about person into project class... Usually we create special class for report, because don't want to change our classes because of report..
But if you want: add Name and Surname.

Comment: I'm create a class for report too :-) check your solution and that works. but Design of the report is not suitable for my needs.

Comment: Show me your design. Have you add grouping?

Comment: do mean UI design? (take screenshot?)

Comment: If you want or just tell me where is mistake.

Comment: There is no mistake here and it's works. but in your way I must create a table for people that grouped by project name. I need a report like that I mentioned in my question. You can see what design I need :)

Comment: I describe you the way you can get the design report you want. Okay. You may update your answer and post result screenshot. I will return later and answer you.